# Submitting a form from email ejs template and use the value in a middleware

Tags: node.js, json, express, ejs

I am sending an ejs email along some parameters (userId and email). Inside the email there is a form that should send this (userId) variable back to the server and should be used in a middleware. However, nodejs does not recognise the req.body...

The ejs form have an input with the value populated to be the userId and should be passed down to the action url...:

```
        <form action="http://localhost:3000/api/allowUser" method="POST">
                <!-- Here i passed the userId as a value and send to email-->
                <input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" value="<%- userId %>"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Allow user" />
            </form>
```

This is the email received with the input value.
[image]

**Outcome:**
Now, the administrator is redirected to the success page by accessing the /allowUser endpoint. Here, I need to use the req.body.userId, but is undefined... I cannot have access even to req object...

```
exports.allowUser = async (req, res, next) => {

    // NEED TO USE THE userId HERE

    let {userId} = req.body;   //Undefined
    console.log(req.body);      //empty object

    res.render('success.ejs', {userId: userId});
}
```

The redirect function works, but the userId cannot be passed or used in the allowUser function.

However, if accessing the network tab in the success page I can see there the userId being present at every refresh. But still not being able to access the variable
[image]

anyone have any ideas please? Many thanks, Daniel

Comment: Have you read **the first paragraph** of the [documentation for `req.body`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for comm. I actually did not. The problem was the EJS syntax.. In the HTML form tag I replaced the first line with ```<form action=<%= `http://localhost:3000/api/allowUser/${userId}` %> method="POST">```

Comment: That should not make any difference at all.

Comment: It is working now. Can you please tell me what I have done wrong in the code? I just read the line and cannot really understand right now...

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you provided. The usual cause for this problem is failing to include a body parsing middleware.

Comment: Aha. I understand. Thank you. I will have a better look. I did used express.json() in the app.js

Comment: `express.json()` won't help. You're not posting JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i can see that your ejs form is correct,but in your req.body you should get userid like this way

```
let user_id=req.body.userId //userId name 
// from ejs form
```

Then render success page

```
res.render("success",{userid:user_id});
//without .ejs in success page
```

Also i think your form action doesn't need the whole link,only the endpoint /allowuser

Make sure that your routes are correct,hope this will help you.Tell me again if problem still exists.

Comment: "you should get userid like this way" — Why? I don't see any reason to avoid destructuring assignment syntax there.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the mistake. It was a syntax problem. I was using the template literal of EJS wrong (i am first tie user of EJS). I replaced the form line with 
```<form action=<%= `http://localhost:3000/api/allowUser/${userId}` %> method="POST">
```